# Proxychains dosen't work, DNS leak test shows location

Tags: proxy, tor, proxychains

I've been trying to use Proxy Chains with Tor but when I launch Firefox with them a DNS Leak test will show exactly where I live. I'm on Linux Mint and I'm using the stranded Firefox, not the Tor browser or something like that. I configured the proxychains.conf file by enabling dynamic_chain and commenting out strict_chain, I've also added socks5 127.0.0.1 9050 to my proxy list. I've been using Linux and the Terminal for about a year now while learning Web Development and I'm trying to learn some security now to better protect my web sites.. I'm completely confused here, thanks so much for any responses :D Here is the full conf file:

```
proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Firefox does not do DNS lookups over the SOCKS proxy. You have to check the appropriate checkbox when configuring the proxy in Firefox. As example see https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB93s.png but in the current version of Firefox the dialog looks slightly different.